# Manifest XML file in the Admin Center environment

Tags: office365, office-js, manifest, office-addins, development-environment

I have the following question that involves the Microsoft Office add-in. After the team has prepared the manifest file and wants to make it available to organizations that will be using this add-in/solution, should the organization be in the Admin Center - Microsoft 365 environment? I ask this, thinking about the distribution of the supplement to the groups of the organization

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways of deploying / sideloading Outlook (Office) mail add-ins:

1. For on-premises and online environments that do not use the Azure AD identity service, you can deploy Outlook add-ins via the Exchange server.

   Outlook add-in deployment requires:

   - Microsoft 365, Exchange Online, or Exchange Server 2013 or later
   - Outlook 2013 or later

   To assign add-ins to tenants, use the Exchange admin center to upload a manifest directly, either from a file or a URL, or add an add-in from AppSource. To assign add-ins to individual users, you must use Exchange PowerShell. For details, see Add-ins for Outlook in Exchange Server.
2. In a cloud deployment, to distribute your add-in to users in your organization by using the Microsoft 365 admin center. See [Test and deploy Microsoft 365 Apps by partners in the Integrated apps portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/test-and-deploy-microsoft-365-apps?view=o365-worldwide) for more infomation.

---

You can find all possible ways of sideloading Office add-ins described in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish#outlook-add-in-deployment) article.